# NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler and production?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

The OmniFaces 2.0 introduced a [NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler). This is a great feature but surely it should be off for production mode?

Even after reading the docs and source I am not sure if it's development mode only or not. Crossing my fingers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed primarily designed as a development aid.

If you already use it from the beginning on when developing a new JSF webapp, or when it's installed only later and you have tests which cover every single page of the webapp, then it shouldn't harm when run in production as well (i.e. it shouldn't throw the ISE).

I can however imagine that it's an unnecessary overhead to keep checking all component IDs in production stage as they are basically already checked during development stage and don't ever change in production stage. Hence, it has been [altered](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/693956d976cab73edf82b1c61ca6d004ec6dbac3) to run in development stage only. It's available as per today's latest snapshot. Documentation will be regenerated later.